# how to do this kind of UI in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```
  Container( child: Column(children: [
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Company",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff676767)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Color(0xff1e1e1e),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: "Title",
                    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff676767)),
                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Color(0xff1e1e1e),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        // borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18),
                        ),
                  ),
                ),
              ]),
            ),
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmYU1.png)
here is my code and a sample image of the problem. couldn't figure out how to do this

Comment: I think you need to set Color(0xff1e1e1e) of the container then disable underline decoration in both textfields.

Comment: yes, thank you. but container has a borderradius circular. can't put it in container

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the container with a cliprrect and adda border radius to it

```dart
ClipRRect(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
  child: Container(
    child: Column(
      children: [
       TextField(),
       TextField()
      ]
    )
  )
),
```

Comment: it works. thank you. it has a focusborder. how can i do this

Comment: The text field has a decoration. In that you can manage focus border, enable border, border and error border

Comment: yes but when selected whole container will focus. not single textformfield

Comment: For for each textfield it can be added

Comment: won't work like this

Comment: Do you want it to highlight the full container?

Comment: yes, for each textfield selected

Answer (score 0):

Use TextFormField's onFieldSubmitted() & onTap() to dynamically change border using FocusNode for Company & Title TextFormField

Initialize FocusNode for both TextField's before build().

Make sure your parent widget is a stateful widget

```
Color borderColor = Colors.transparent;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        // backgroundColor: Colo,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                child: Container(
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Colors.grey[800],
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        border: Border.all(
                            color: companyFN.hasFocus || titleFN.hasFocus
                                ? Colors.blue
                                : Colors.transparent)
                        // border: Border.all(color: borderColor)
                        ),
                    child: Column(children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          focusNode: companyFN,
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              borderColor = Colors.blue;
                            });
                          },
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            setState(() {
                              borderColor = Colors.transparent;
                            });
                          },
                          decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                            hintText: "Company",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextFormField(
                          focusNode: titleFN,
                          decoration: const InputDecoration.collapsed(
                            hintText: "Title",
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                          ),
                          onTap: () {
                            setState(() {
                              borderColor = Colors.blue;
                            });
                          },
                          onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                            setState(() {
                              borderColor = Colors.transparent;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ])),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
```

OUTPUT:

[image]

[image]

Comment: it's showing "LateInitializationError: Field 'titleFN' has not been initialized." this error.
maybe my node initialization isn't right.
though my reputation isn't 15, i can't vote to any right or wrong answer. hope you would understand

Comment: Before build() method initialise your nodes like FocusNode titleFN = FocusNode(); same way FocusNode companyFN = FocusNode ();

Comment: yea.
it was all right. didn't know why the error show. the main problem is ""when i tap another field focus mode don't go away form companyfn or titlefn. if the whole form is disposed, still it's focus. what to do?

Comment: Share your entire build() method code

Comment: override
  void initState() {
    
    super.initState();
    companyFN = FocusNode();
    titleFN = FocusNode();
  }

  override
  void dispose() {
    // Clean up the focus node when the Form is disposed.
    companyFN.dispose();
    titleFN.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }